# Add Rounded Corners to Left navigation in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, style.css

I can find information on rounded corners for Webparts, but looking for rounded corners for left navigation in SharePoint Online.

Any pointer will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS rule:

```
#sideNavBox {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: But if the DIV color is white and the element behind the DIV is white you won't see much